# Quotes in Command Line

Tags: java, command-line, lftp

I'm attempting to make a maven plugin for LFTP and that involves invoking the LFTP command line program from my java application.

However I am unable to get it to process my passed in commands using single quotes, double quotes, espcaped single / double quotes.

What I have for code so far is:

```
final String command = "lftp -e 'set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; put -O /data/upload/ src/test/resources/test-file.txt; bye' -u username,password -p 21 192.168.1.100"
final CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(command.toString());
final DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setWorkingDirectory(new File(baseDir));
final int result = executor.execute(cmdLine);
```

And what looking for suggestions on what to try next.

**Edit #1:** I have attempted to utilize `org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine` and as a pre-done String but it results in the following error:

```
Unknown command `set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; put -O /data/upload/ src/test/resources/test-file.txt; bye'.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147)
    at org.welsh.build.automation.lftp.plugin.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:30)
```

But when I print out the generated command and run that manually it works fine.

**Edit #2:** Added some more clarity.

Comment: Isn't there an executor of some sort which takes an array of strings as an argument instead of a single string?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters

Comment: @baba I don't think this is related since here, it is a question of executing an external command

Comment: @fge external or not, using sun API's is not recommended. That is why a better library like Commons Cli can do wonders compared to trying to manually parse quotes and single quotes with a deprecated API.

Comment: @baba that is _not_ the question at all. The question here is to have the ability to invoke a command with separate arguments. Commons-cli will do _nothing_ for that, since quotes etc are handled by the _shell_.

Comment: @fge of course, if a command is invalid, no library will help you. My suggestion to Welsh is to make the command work on shell and then execute it with a non-deprecated library, like the Commons Cli.

Comment: @baba I think he's trying to execute an external command from his program and not write a program with that accepts command line options.

Comment: @LeeMeador that is what I have been trying to tell him ;)

Comment: @babe LeeMeador and Fge are correct in their assumption. I am trying to invoke the LFTP program from my java program. The issue is, when I print my command that is produced from either CommandLine or as a pre-done String it works in Command Line through a manual execution but won't work from my Java Program.

Answer (score 4):

Commons-exec stresses that it's easier to deal with `CommandLine` instances by building incrementally:

```
final CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("lftp");
cmdLine.addArgument("-e");
cmdLine.addArgument("set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; put -O /data/upload/ src/test/resources/test-file.txt; bye");
...
executor.execute(cmdLine);
```

I haven't looked at their command line parser, but if they don't fully trust it, I wouldn't, either.

Comment: I've attempted to utilize this, but it produced the error in my edit.  In the send that what should be encased in quotes is seen as a second command and not as part of the LFTP command.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples here:

[Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html)

Notice that they do not use single quote (') characters but rather build a java string with double quotes by preceeding the double quote character with a backslash.

Here is the one example showing that:

```
String line = "AcroRd32.exe /p /h \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
```

Here is another way to build the command line:

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("lftp");
cmdLine.addArgument("-e");
cmdLine.addArgument("set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; put -O /data/upload/ src/test/resources/test-file.txt; bye");
cmdLine.addArgument("-u");
cmdLine.addArgument("username,password");
cmdLine.addArgument("-p");
cmdLine.addArgument("21");
cmdLine.addArgument("192.168.1.100");
```